# ARC app not compatible on desktop chrome

Tags: google-chrome-arc

We have generated ARC app using ARC welder app. It was working fine on Chromebook and desktop versions of Chrome. But after we submitted it to Chrome web store, it is showing **NOT COMPATIBLE** on desktop chrome. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Because ARC is not for desktop Chrome at this time.

Quoting [the first sentence of the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc):

> The App Runtime for Chrome (Beta), or ARC, lets you run your favorite Android apps on Chrome OS.

Right now, desktop Chrome is a development tool for ARC. Whether ARC apps will be distributable to desktop Chrome in the future is anyone's guess.

Comment: That's really strange. I was expecting that it will be available to all platforms as the same app package works fine on desktop if you add it manually.

Comment: @Vivek: I will be stunned if ARC apps are not *eventually* available for desktop Chrome. My guess is that the "beta" description and Chrome OS limitation is to intentionally slow the rollout while we work out the kinks in the ARC process. ARC has its issues (e.g., no lifecycle events if the user closes the window), and my guess is that Google will hold off on distribution to desktop Chrome until things are more solid. All of this is just speculation on my part. Imagine a grain of salt about 12cm on a side, and take that grain of salt with my predictions. :-)